# Setup Mercurial Repository with Jenkins and Jenkins Job?

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, mercurial-hook

I need to setup Jenkins to use a Mercurial Repository hosted on BitBucket but running into issues when the job tries to poll the repository.

Example URL:

> hg clone https://joeblogs@bitbucket.org/joeblogs/test2

I'm also attempting to align inside Jenkins 'Global Tool Configuration' as listed below:
[image]

I have also attempted to align the Jenkins job as listed:
[image]

When the job polls the SCM I'am seeing the following message:

```
Started on Jul 4, 2019 3:13:00 PM
Polling SCM changes on master
FATAL: SCM revision state is not a Mercurial one
java.io.IOException: SCM revision state is not a Mercurial one
    at hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(MercurialSCM.java:410)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(SCM.java:400)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.poll(SCM.java:417)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.pollWithWorkspace(AbstractProject.java:1412)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject._poll(AbstractProject.java:1382)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.poll(AbstractProject.java:1293)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.runPolling(SCMTrigger.java:603)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.run(SCMTrigger.java:649)
    at hudson.util.SequentialExecutionQueue$QueueEntry.run(SequentialExecutionQueue.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Done. Took 2 ms
No changes
```

Please note my instance of Jenkins is running in the AWS cloud and uses a Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Comment: There was a radio button like 'Legacy' or whatever. Try setup Mercurial there. The actual Mercurial plugin is unusable in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to no branch named default on your version control. If you want to use the master branch please leave the place as blank.